# Me muestra muchisimos numeros cuando intento mostrar una matriz c++

Tags: c++, matriz, array-bidimensional

tengo el problema de que cuando intento mostrar el los numeros introducidos, me salen muchisimos numeros que no deberian estar en la matriz. El código es el siguiente:

Tengo delimitada la matriz por las constantes que estan al principio, y son las que uso para controlar los bucles for que leen y escriben la matriz, entonces realmente no entiendo cual puede ser el problema. El '/t' al final de la funcion mostrar matriz lo tengo puesto porque me lo enseñaron en clase, pero realmente tampoco entiendo su funcion, solo se que sin el, no se muestran los numeros. Perdonen las molestias y muchas gracias

```
   #include <iostream>

   #include <array>
   using namespace std;

   const int N_Filas=2;

   const int N_Columnas=3;

   typedef array <int,N_Columnas> Filas;

   typedef array <Filas,N_Filas> matriz;

   typedef array<int,N_Filas> columna;

  void rellenarmatriz( matriz &a);


  void mostarmatriz(matriz &a);

  int main(){

    matriz b;

    rellenarmatriz(b);
    mostarmatriz (b);


    return 0;
}

  void rellenarmatriz( matriz &a){


    cout<<" introduzca la matriz fila a fila "<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<N_Filas;i++){


        for(int j=0;j<N_Columnas;j++){


            cin>>a[i][j];
        }

        cout<<endl;
           

    }

  }


   void mostarmatriz(matriz &a){


for(int i=0;i<N_Filas;i++){



    for(int j=0;i<N_Columnas;j++){


        cout<<a[i][j]<<'\t';


       }

         cout<<endl;
         }

  }
```

Este es el resultado:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En tu método `mostrarmatriz` en el segundo `for` (j), la condición para salir del `for` lo haces con la variable `i` en lugar de `j`. Aqui la `i` representa el número de fila y `j` el número de columna. Esta función lo que hace ir mostrando por cada fila el valor de la columna. En pocas palabras mostrar la Matriz.

Por otro lado tu variable `matriz` debe esta definida así:

```
typedef array <Filas,N_Columnas> matriz;
```

Filas x Columnas de modo tal que esté conforme a tu metodo `rellenamatriz`.

Así como está  no debería salir del for y debe salir un error cuando `j` pase de `N_Columnas`porque la condición nunca se va a dar. Debería ser así:

```
// Por cada fila (i) de la matriz
for(int i=0;i<N_Filas;i++){  
    // y por cada columna (j) 
    for(int j=0;j<N_Columnas;j++){
        cout<<a[i][j]<<'\t'; // mostrar el valor de la celda e imprimir un tabulación (\t) de modo tal que cada valor no se muestren juntos. Sin `t`, por ejemplo, 234 y no se verían realmente las columnas. El `\t` hace que se vea 2 3 4. 
       }
      cout<<endl;// Dejar una linea en blanco para la proxima linea.
     }
  }
```

Por otro lado, te muestra cualquier numero porque ya está tomando valores fuera de la matriz y toma lo que encuentre en memoria. Supongo que aparte de imprimirte así al final te debe estar dando una excepción.